# Char cast to int in C returns negative value

Tags: c, arrays, binary

I'm working on an assignment, and as apart of it, I need to convert integers (their source is text document into an array and then write then to another file as binary.
I created an array, which stores all the data (the assignment suggested to do so). I converted the numbers using `atoi` function, they converted perfectly. 
I am inserting these numbers into the array using bit shifting:

```
arr[index] = (integer >> 16) && 0xFF;
arr[index+1] = (integer >> 8) && 0xFF;
arr[index+2] = integer && 0xFF;
```

but when I'm trying to pull the numbers back out (I'm testing the method):

```
integer = 0;
integer |= (arr[index]<<16);
integer |= (arr[index+1]<<8);
integer |= (arr[index+2]);
```

for example, I've done it to the number 76234. It's memory representation (in the char array) was:
`1,41,-54`

after running the above code to convert it back, it returned an odd result into `integer`: `-54`.
I've done some debugging in gdb, and everything worked perfectly fine until the third line of converting back:

```
(gdb) p /t (arr[23])
$4 = 11001010
(gdb) p /t (int)(arr[23])
$5 = 11111111111111111111111111001010
```

So, in casting from char->int it returns -54 which causes odd results. Is there any way to get the "real" value in this byte, and not the negative one? or is there a better way to store the data (It's some kind of assembler for an imaginary 24-bit CPU, so I have to store it in 24-byte units, which are 3 bytes, which is one char so it seems the best solution for me)?
Thanks

Comment: Define `arr` to be an array of `unsigned char` rather than ‘char`. If you cannot do that, cast each value from the array to `unsigned char` each time you use it.

Comment: `&& 0xFF` is wrong. Use `& 0xFF`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Typing mistake, meant to the bitwise & operator. I’ll try unsigned char. Thx!